# How can I calculate the average number of relationships each node has in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, divide

Stuck in finding the avg number of relationships each node has. I know how to find the number of nodes and the number of relationships in total. But I can't combine them into one query. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach. This is for getting this info for all nodes regardless of label:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, size((n)--()) as relCount
RETURN avg(relCount) as averageRelCount
```

If you're trying to return this information in addition to total nodes and total relationships, then you should read this knowledge base article on [getting fast counts from the counts store](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/fast-counts-using-the-count-store/). It can get you those totals, though it can't get you the average rel count as above.

You can combine them by using the counts store early in the query, and the average relationship part at the end.

Here's how you might use it if you use APOC Procedures to select the counts you want from the store:

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD nodeCount, relCount as totalRelCount
MATCH (n)
WITH n, size((n)--()) as relCount, nodeCount, totalRelCount
RETURN avg(relCount) as averageRelCount, nodeCount, totalRelCount
```